# Python: referring to each duplicate item in a list by unique index

Tags: list, python-3.x, text, indexing, duplicates

I am trying to extract particular lines from txt output file. The lines I am interested in are few lines above and few below the key_string that I am using to search through the results. The key string is the same for each results.

```
fi = open('Inputfile.txt')
fo = open('Outputfile.txt', 'a')

lines = fi.readlines()
filtered_list=[]

for item in lines:
    if item.startswith("key string"):
        filtered_list.append(lines[lines.index(item)-2])
        filtered_list.append(lines[lines.index(item)+6])
        filtered_list.append(lines[lines.index(item)+10])
        filtered_list.append(lines[lines.index(item)+11])       
fo.writelines(filtered_list)

fi.close()
fo.close()
```

The output file contains the right lines for the first record, but multiplied for every record available. How can I update the indexing so it can read every individual record? I've tried to find the solution but as a novice programmer I was struggling to use enumerate() function or collections package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it would probably help if you said what exactly goes wrong with your code (a stack trace, it doesn't work at all, etc). Anyway, here's some thoughts. You can try to divide your problem into subproblems to make it easier to work with. In this case, let's separate finding the relevant lines from collecting them.

First, let's find the indexes of all the relevant lines.

```
key = "key string"
relevant = []
for i, item in enumerate(lines):
    if item.startswith(key):
        relevant.append(item)
```

`enumerate` is actually quite simple. It takes a list, and returns a sequence of (index, item) pairs. So, `enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c'])` returns `[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]`.

What I had written above can be achieved with a list comprehension:

```
relevant = [i for (i, item) in enumerate(lines) if item.startswith(key)]
```

So, we have the indexes of the relevant lines. Now, let's collected them. You are interested in the line 2 lines before it and 6 and 10 and 11 lines after it. If your first lines contains the key, then you have a problem – you don't really want `lines[-1]` – that's the last item! Also, you need to handle the situation in which your offset would take you past the end of the list: otherwise Python will raise an `IndexError`.

```
out = []
for r in relevant:
    for offset in -2, 6, 10, 11:
        index = r + offset
        if 0 < index < len(lines):
            out.append(lines[index])
```

You could also catch the `IndexError`, but that won't save us much typing, as we have to handle negative indexes anyway.

The whole program would look like this:

```
key = "key string"
with open('Inputfile.txt') as fi:
    lines = fi.readlines()

relevant = [i for (i, item) in enumerate(lines) if item.startswith(key)]
out = []
for r in relevant:
    for offset in -2, 6, 10, 11:
        index = r + offset
        if 0 < index < len(lines):
            out.append(lines[index])

with open('Outputfile.txt', 'a') as fi:
    fi.writelines(out)
```

Comment: Thanks Ryszard! This was exactly what I was looking for. The problem was that extracted data was only the first record duplicated by number of the records in output file. It is due to the fact that python 'list.index' method have some limitations. Below part of the 'list.index' method description from python 3.6 documentation: "The returned index is computed relative to the beginning of the full sequence rather than the start argument.".

Answer (score -1):

To get rid of duplicates you can cast list to set; example:

```
x=['a','b','a']
y=set(x)
print(y)
```

will result in:
['a','b']

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However I need these duplicates to use them as anchors to extract the data I want. Unfortunately your answer will not help me.